# PHP - Why current date not same with date inside database?

Tags: php, mysql

I just got the problem regarding to `datetime` issue. I just insert the data into the database and compare with current datetime, it seems a problem.

SQL query

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(lastWarnDate) VALUES(NOW())");
```

My PHP code

```
//$result["lastWarnDate"] = "2014-10-20 22:00:49"

$datetime1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$datetime2 = strtotime($result["lastWarnDate"]);
$interval  = abs($datetime2 - $datetime1);
$minutes   = round($interval / 60);

//$datetime1 = 2014-10-21 02:11:44
//$datetime2 = 2014-10-20 22:00:49
```

My timezone is `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur`. My server located in Singapore. I'm using Digital Ocean server.

The output straightly show up after I insert the data.

Comment: do you know what is timezone?

Comment: What did you insert into the database?

Comment: May be your server is located somewhere else in different timezone?

Comment: Can you show the line where you insert the date into the database. I want to see exactly what you are inserting.

Comment: I would *highly* recommend storing UTC (or better UTC + offset/TZ) in the database ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. The most correct answer is using `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` instead `NOW()`.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

> define('TIMEZONE', 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');

In Mysql (or other PDO compatible database)

> $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'dbuser',
> 'dbpassword');
>
> $db->exec("SET time_zone='Asia/Kuala_Lumpur';");

A elegant solution to automatically configure the database's timezone based on the timezone set in PHP is well provided by SitePoint [synchronize php mysql timezone configuration](http://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/)

Comment: not working, my current is 2014-10-21 04:55:14. It suppose to be 2014-10-21 12:55:14

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin You could always bypass the problem by just adding the right hours as the time zone offset to the database, so that it matches you php install. In you case it would be $db->exec("SET time_zone='+08:00';");

Answer (score 0):

Go to [MySQL Website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html)

and download "**POSIX standard Time zone description tables, version 2011n**" and update it in your db as per site instructions. You will get it done.

Comment: Yes. you can update in mariDB also. In MySQL, I used to place the downloaded timzone files(POSIX standard Time zone description tables, version 2011n) in 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql'. So check your directory  and place your downloaded files in C:....\mysql\data\mysql

Comment: how about if i'm using centos 7?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your system timezone is not matched with the server. Open mysql console and put in your timezone, something like this: `SET GLOBAL time_zone = "+06:00";` considering the gap. Then restart mysql.